# sailsjs getting all controller names and action(method) name within the controllerss

Tags: controller, sails.js

I am working on a sailsjs project and i need to extract/find all of my available controllers within my api folder. I will also need to find all of the actions(method) available within those controllers.

A dumb way of getting the controller names would probably be to go to the directory and find all file names, but how do i get the actions? I believe there should be an easier method/way of getting the controller and action names?

Edit:
I am able to get the controller names by doing the following:

```
getControllers: function(req,res){
  var _ = require('lodash');
  var controllerList = [];

  var controllers = _(sails.controllers).toArray().value();
  for (var i=0;i<controllers.length;i++){
    controllerList.push(controllers[i].globalId);
  }
  res.json({error:null, data:controllerList});
}
```

If for example my controller has 1 action in it, when i tried the following, instead of returning 1 result, it returns 4, and the result is something not very readable, i just need the name of the action:

```
var actons = _(sails.controllers.controllerName).toArray().value();
for (var i=0;i<actions.length;i++){
  actionList.push(controllers[i].action);
}
```

Am i doing something wrong? I understand that most information are bring stored inside sails. So am i using a wrong keyword? Is 'sails.controllers..action' wrong? After searching for a long time i found that 'globalId' is the keyword for the controller name, is there one for action name as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will display you all controller names with action names in it. Now you can do anything you want with it.

```
_.each(sails.controllers, function(controller, controllerId) {
    _.each(controller, function(action, actionId) {
        if (actionId != 'sails' || _.isString(action) || _.isBoolean(action) || action === false) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(controllerId + ' ' + actionId);

    });
});
```

Comment: Your solution worked great! Except for 1 mistake i think. Instead of putting "actionId != 'sails'", changing it to "action == 'sails'" worked fine!